# RavenDB Dependency Issue with .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ravendb, .net-core

I'm trying to create an embedded database in .NET Core using RavenDB. While the RavenDB.Client package is restoring without any issues, the RavenDB.Database package (which is required to make an embedded database) is not restoring properly even though it's only dependency is RavenDB.Client. I am receiving an error message which states that RavenDB.Database is not compatible with .netcoreapp1.0. Here's a picture of my package.json:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Package RavenDB.Database 3.5.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)`. Thus not supported on `netcoreapp1.0`. You can also download the https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/RavenDB.Database/3.5.0 package, extract and look at the `lib` folder to see what it supports.

Since `RavenDB.Client` supports `netstandard1.3` it is supported on `netcoreapp1.0` via the following analogy by David Fowler:

```
interface INetCoreApp10 : INetStandard15 //What we care about in this case
{

}

interface INetStandard10
{
    void Primitives();
    void Reflection();
    void Tasks();
    void Collections();
    void Linq();
}

interface INetStandard11 : INetStandard10
{
    void ConcurrentCollections();
    void InteropServices();
}

interface INetStandard12 : INetStandard11
{
    void ThreadingTimer();
}

interface INetStandard13 : INetStandard12 //NetStandard version this library supports
{
    void FileSystem();
    void Console();
    void ThreadPool();
    void Process();
    void Sockets();

    void AsyncLocal();
}

interface INetStandard14 : INetStandard13
{
    void IsolatedStorage();
}

interface INetStandard15 : INetStandard14
{
    void AssemblyLoadContext();
}
```

https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7#file-_platform-cs-L127

**TLDR;** Use .NET 4.5 instead of .NET Core if you want to consume this library. Or wait until this library is ported to .NET Core.

To do so, change your `frameworks` in your `project.json` to the respective item:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net45": {
  }
}
```

**Note:** You will also need to remove the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I knew this would fix the issue, however it seems odd to me that the library hasn't been ported over when it depends on a library that has been. Thanks again for the elaborate response.

Comment: @Bryan: Why would it be odd? `RavenDB.Client` has only a subset of APIs that's required for `RavenDB.Database`, so of course it can consume it. But if `RavenDB.Database` may depend on API currently only available on full .NET Framework, then its not possible to port it with big overhead and take way longer.